# Finding a handwritten dataset with an already extracted features

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, handwriting

I want to test my clustering algorithms on data of handwritten text, so I'm searching for a dataset of handwritten text (e.g. words) with already extracted features (the goal is to test my clustering algorithms on, not to extract features). Does anyone have any information on that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dataset of images of handwritten *digits* : http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ .

Comment: Yes, I've already tested on this database using the 28*28 pixels values of each image as feature vector. But I want more to have an extracted features (descriptors) from a set of handwritten words, characters, or digits ...

Answer (score 0):

[Texmex](http://corpus-texmex.irisa.fr) has 128d [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) vectors
"to evaluate the quality of approximate 
nearest neighbors search algorithm on different kinds of data and varying database sizes",
but I don't know what their images are of; you could try asking the authors.

Comment: The dataset corpus-texmex is intended for the evaluation of approximate nearest neighbor search methods only.